# why don't multiple cameras work on windows

Tags: windows, usb, python, camera

I'm trying to connect two cameras both with two lenses that are connected to two separate USB ports. the problem is that only one cam works at the time. Is that even possible? my goal is to connect multiple cameras to a single computer to run a command via python. any advice?

once I run the python command along with the script, a visualizer should pop up. The visualizer shows only two screens from one camera (each had two lenses) instead of four. I am thinking its a power issue since one camera set is receiving power and the other is not.

Comment: Please consider [edit]ing this question to include more details about what you are actually doing. In my experience, Windows drivers can limit the number of cameras "available" but something like say Python and OpenCV may not have that limitation.

Comment: This is not the default behavior of webcams within windows.  (free) [SkyStudio](https://skystudiopro.com) can do it.  I am betting that your simple python script will fall short of whatever hoops that engineer had to jump through.  You might hit up the author of that app to see if they will give you any hints.

Comment: @Anaksunaman hey thank you. Sorry about that. I’ll try to edit. I’m using a windows computer. Currently, when I run the python command for the script(prebuilt script should run without errors)  it’ll only show you two screens, instead of four. Two of those screens coming from one camera. The other camera  Should show the other two. What I’ve noticed is that one camera will receive power over the other. So I’m thinking it’s a power distribution issue. What do you think?

Comment: `I’m thinking it’s a power distribution issue` .. Not a chance.  These are USB ports and I guarantee that your devices are able to get power even when not active (the light on the camera is lit).  It's a high level API either/or issue.  Chances are that the SkyStudio guy did not write device drivers to circumvent this problem so it is unlikely that this problem exists at the driver layer.

Comment: That makes sense. I did notice if I shuffled USB’s the other camera would turn on, and the other would be off. So it’s probably how the device drivers are configured?  Or are you saying the problem is the code/API in use? @SeñorCMasMas

Comment: I am GUESSING (not saying) that two cameras are being prevented from working at the API level.  There are lower level calls that you could make (probably not from python) to get around this because other people have done so.

Comment: In python you have to address each camera independently.  First capture and display camera 1 and then camera 2.  This is not automatic.

Comment: @cybernard both cameras work on my desktop. I am able to see all 4 screens when I run my python script. Now my issue on my second desktop, is that the USB's are not detected. How can I manually get access to the usb port and camera from windows? I believe this is a windows issues.

Comment: Are they both windows 10?  Are you plugging them into USB 3.0 ports on both computers.  It is possible you might not have the right drivers installed for you USB ports.  USB 2.0 ports max at 500ma and 3.0 allow 900ma so they could be under powered.